# How to disallow users to upload non-PDF files using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap-Vue and Vue2. I would like to use the [Form File Input](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-file) to allow users to upload the files. But the format of the files should be PDF only. So I used `accept="application/pdf"`:

```
<b-form-file
    v-model="fileLoc"
    browse-text="choose"
    accept="application/pdf"
/>
```

But when browsing, I can still choose "All" and choose non PDF file:

[image]

How can I make sure that the users uploads only files in PDF format?

Comment: It is not possible to hide that option. In any case, if someone is trying to upload something incorrect, nothing is stopping them from renaming another file to end with `.pdf` and uploading it. You need to check the uploaded file on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the answer is in the link you provided :-)

"Note: Not all browsers support or respect the accept attribute on file inputs."

If you want to make sure that the user uploaded a pdf file, I suggest you to write a function for that (and please make also a server validation since the user could have switched the extension of a file to pdf).